# Why does the 'digits' argument in R's print change a value?

Tags: r

Why does the function return a value `t = 13.214`, but `print(..., digits = 3)` returns `t = 10`?

```
vals <- data.frame(a = c(4, 2, 4, 7, 3, 4, 8, 8, 3, 0, 1, 5, 4, 6, 4, 8, 7, 9, 6, 6, 3, 6, 7, 4), 
                   b = c(5, 7, 6, 13, 12, 6, 14, 16, 4, 2, 7, 7, 4, 8, 9, 9, 11, 13, 12, 8, 3, 8, 7, 7))
stats::t.test(x = vals)
# One Sample t-test
# data:  vals
# t = 13.214, df = 47, p-value < 2.2e-16
# alternative hypothesis: true mean is not equal to 0
# 95 percent confidence interval:
#   5.598761 7.609572
# sample estimates:
#   mean of x 
# 6.604167 
print(stats::t.test(x = vals), digits = 3)
```

Form `?print`:

> digits: minimal number of significant digits, see print.default.

But that should not change 10 to 13?

**package ‘stats’ version 3.5.1**
**R.version**
platform       x86_64-w64-mingw32
arch           x86_64
os             mingw32
system         x86_64, mingw32
status
major          3
minor          5.1
year           2018
month          07
day            02
svn rev        74947
language       R
version.string R version 3.5.1 (2018-07-02)
nickname       Feather Spray

Comment: It looks like it is rounding the numbers. Check how `df` also goes from 47 to 50.

Comment: Not an answer, but notice what happens when you try higher values of digits: 3, 4, 5

Comment: Interesting note in `?print.htest`: "Both print methods traditionally have not obeyed the digits argument properly. They now do, the htest method mostly in expressions like max(1, digits - 2)."

Comment: Cannot reproduce this behavior in R 3.6. What version of R are you running? Update R version?

Comment: The method being called is `print.htest` and many of the values are being formatted with `digits - 2`, so if `digits = 3` you're left with only one sig digit.

Comment: @RuiBarradas See my edit. Why should R version affect `print.htest`?

Comment: @joran First: How did you figure out, it is `print.htest`? I tried debugging but without success. On the other hand `print(13.214, digits = 1)` results in `13`.

Comment: @Christoph Because R versions change things, especially to fix bugs. The [release notes for 3.6.0](https://cran.r-project.org/doc/manuals/r-release/NEWS.html) include *"Arguments supplied to print() are now properly forwarded to methods when printing lists, pairlists or attributes containing S3 objects."* It seems like you may have found a bug that's already been fixed.

Comment: First, `x <- stats::t.test(x = vals); class(x)` to see what the class of the object is. Second, your other example behaves differently because that's calling a different print method, which naturally may make different choices about how to handle that argument.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first step in answering these questions is always to figure out which print method we're dealing with. The generic help in `?print` won't necessarily be terribly relevant. t.test objects have class `htest`, so we want to look at `print.htest`.

Note that `?print.htest` sends you to a slightly more specific documentation page. The documentation for `digits` doesn't say anything specific, but then in the Details section we see:

> Both print methods traditionally have not obeyed the digits argument
>   properly. They now do, the htest method mostly in expressions like
>   max(1, digits - 2).

(This is in R 3.5.2)

For example, in the function code we see things like:

```
out <- c(out, paste(names(x$statistic), "=", format(signif(x$statistic, 
            max(1L, digits - 2L)))))
```

The default value for `digits` will typically be 7. It uses `digits` for printing the sample estimates and confidence intervals, but fewer digits for other quantities.

Comment: How do you view the code? I can type `?print.htest` and the help page shows up, but typing just `print.htest` results in "Error: object 'print.htest' not found"

Comment: @IceCreamToucan Sorry, yes, it's an unexported methos in **stats**, so you need to type `stats:::print.htest`. When you do `methods("print")` the ones with stars after them are unexported. Looking in **stats** was just an educated guess, since it's going to be in one of the base packages, and stats makes the most sense.

Comment: @IceCreamToucan Another way is `getAnywhere(print.htest)`.