# Do R classes change numeric values?

Tags: r

As I already had similar problems [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/56061887/5784831), I just hit another question: `stats::t.test` returns a `p-value < 2.2e-16`. But from maths I get `p_value <- 2 * pt(-abs(t), df) # [1] 1.929352e-17`. What is wrong?

I just started debugging as suggested there:

```
debug(stats:::t.test.default)
vals <- data.frame(a = c(4, 2, 4, 7, 3, 4, 8, 8, 3, 0, 1, 5, 4, 6, 4, 8, 7, 
                         9, 6, 6, 3, 6, 7, 4), 
                   b = c(5, 7, 6, 13, 12, 6, 14, 16, 4, 2, 7, 7, 4, 8, 9, 9, 
                         11, 13, 12, 8, 3, 8, 7, 7))

stats::t.test(x = vals)
# One Sample t-test
# data:  vals
# t = 13.214, df = 47, p-value < 2.2e-16
```

Then you step through until you reach line 98,

[image]

where `pval` is evaluated as `1.929352e-17`, which I expected.
This remains unchanged until line 112, where the class is set `class(rval) <- "htest"`.

[image]

What is wrong? Do classes change values? Unfortunately, I don't know, how to understand / debug the code behind line 112.

Comment: @MrFlick I would have expected that typing `stats::t.test(x = vals)` in the console gives the same values as e.g. in `stats::t.test(x = vals)$p.value`? I never saw that behaviour...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No. Classes don't change values, but they do change how they are printed. Since the class that's being returned is a `htest` object, the `stats:::print.htest()` is used to draw the result. To make things prettyier, this function formats numbers so they have a reasonable number of decimal places. It uses the `format.pval` function to make p-values look pretty. After p-values get really small it doesn't really make sense to show all the digits so R just tells you at some point it's less than a certian value. For example

```
format.pval(1e-20)
# [1] "< 2.22e-16
```

The "real" value is still stored in the object

```
x <- stats::t.test(x = vals)
x$p.value
# [1] 1.929352e-17
```

This is a very common pattern in R where just `print()`ing a value doesn't necessarily show what's "really" there; it's just a pretty display of that object.

Comment: So typing `stats::t.test(x = vals)` in the console also calls a print method?

Comment: Yes. Anything you type at the console is automatically print()ed by default. The console is a REPL: read, evaluate, print, loop.

Comment: Cool, the first time, I realize that! I also checked: `r <- stats::t.test(x = vals)`, then
`class(r) <- NULL` then `r`!

Comment: you can use `unclass` for this, so you don't damage your objects :),